# Swift: cast closure parameters?

Tags: parameters, casting, closures, swift

The following code causes the compiler error: `Could not find member 'Left'`.

```
let indexOfConstraint = constraints.indexOfObjectPassingTest { (constraint, idx, stop) in
    return constraint.firstAttribute == .Left
}
```

Prepending `NSLayoutAttribute` before `.Left` fixes the error, but is there a way to cast `constraint` to `NSLayoutConstraint`?

For example, in Objective-C, I could cast `constraint` when specifying the parameters.

```
NSUInteger indexOfConstraint = [constraints indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeft
}];
```

Comment: have you tried `(constraint as NSLayoutConstraint).firstAttribute`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the best option. I realized that worked after asking this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to cast:

```
let indexOfConstraint = constraints.indexOfObjectPassingTest { (constraint, idx, stop) in
    return (constraint as NSLayoutConstraint).firstAttribute == .Left
}
```

... Which is arguably uglier than just using `NSLayoutAttribute.Left`

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll just stick with the latter. Thanks! :-)